# What is the most efficient way to retrieve a particular section of text from a string

Tags: vb.net, string, substring, string-matching

Consider the following result set from a search carried out on some xml returned from a service.

[image]

I need to extract the value from the internalref attribute from this (it's at the end of the last but one line in the messagebox representation illustrated).  Firstly by the time that I get this it is no longer valid xml but a string.  Secondly it might not contain an internalref value (That bit at least is easy I can check if resultset.contains("internalref")).

So assuming that it does I could do an index search that would provide the index at which internalref starts and by definition I could add 13 to that to get me to the start of the bit that I'm interested in.

Taking that as a starting point I could search for the index of the next quotation mark and then return the characters at the index points in between.

I can't help but think that there's probably an easier way to do this though and I'm overly complicating things.  The initial check for the existence of internalref is a given but if there's an easier way to extract the bit of the string between the ensuing quotation marks I'd love to know how to do it.  The number that I'm after (and yes it will need to be converted but that's not the issue could be any length from 1 to 15 characters.

Comment: Why is it no longer valid XML? It would make your life tremendously easier if it were. Otherwise there’s nothing for it but to parse it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to do this time of parsing with XML, SelectNode, and XPath, but here's a quick and dirty that should work. Assuming that you have already determined that *internalref=* exists and has no spaces, then try:

```
Dim i As Integer = CInt(Val(Split(s, "internalref=""")(1)))
```

I'm assuming that the number is an integer, but if its a double then remove the call to CInt.

```
Dim i As double = Val(Split(s, "internalref=""")(1))
```

Comment: @DomSinclair Thanks. I should have mentioned that I'm assuming that the string is in a variable called *s*, which you figured out but I mention it for the benefit of anyone reading this post.